# Changing color interval of raster layer in QGIS?

Tags: raster

I have a map with a raster layer that I took from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/tag/world-file/) website.

[image]

My client wanted me to transfer the sea color so it will look black, and the landmass into gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have look into it and find a good solution.
For started I changed color sets into "Singleband pseudocolor" in the "layer styling" window.[image]
Then I went to "Color" and clicked on the "New color ramp..."[image]

In this step the color gradient is on default mode  [image]
I head changed the color gradient into black to gray.[image]
The sea changed is color into black, but I needed the black color to be darker.[image]
In order of doing so I head changed the Min value into 124 and the sea become in a darker black.[image]